Zero neighborhood for LF-topology
The following is exercise 13.3 from Trèves' Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels, page 134.

Let $E$ be a normed space, whose norm is denoted by $\| \|$. Let, for
every $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$, $E_k$ be a linear subspace of $E$ of
dimension $k$, such that $E_k \subset E_{k+1}$. Let $E_{\infty}$ be
the union of the subspaces $E_k$, equipped with the $LF$ topology
defined by means of the sequence $\{E_k\}$. Let $\{\epsilon_k\} \ (k =
> 0, 1, \ldots)$ be a decreasing sequence, converging to $0$, of numbers
$> 0$. Set $$ \mathcal{V} (\{\epsilon_k\}) = \{x \in E_{\infty} ; x
> \notin E_k \Rightarrow \|x\| < \epsilon_k, \ k = 0, 1, \ldots \}. $$
Prove that $\mathcal{V} (\{\epsilon_k\})$ is not a neighborhood of
zero in $E_{\infty}$.

Now, $\mathcal{V} (\{\epsilon_k\})$ is open in $E_\infty$ iff $\mathcal{V} (\{\epsilon_k\}) \cap E_k$ is open in $E_k$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}$).
But for any $k$, this contains the ball of radius $\epsilon_{k-1}$ restricted to $E_k$, so I would say that it is a zero neighborhood.
What is wrong with my argument?
